# Get the reference of a structure throught a trait

Tags: rust

I have the following code ([link to Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2f9ad593ddac97b9d599326530a7afcc)):

```rust
struct News {
    size: u32,
    date: &'static str,
}

struct Journal {
    lst_news: Vec<News>,
}

trait GetNews {
    fn get_news(&self) -> Vec<&News>;
}

impl GetNews for Journal {
    fn get_news(&self) -> Vec<&News> {
        let mut news_list: Vec<&News> = Vec::new();
        for ii in &self.lst_news {
            news_list.push(ii)
        }
        news_list
    }
}

fn news_filter<T: GetNews>(media: T) -> Vec<&News> {
    let mut news_list: Vec<&News> = Vec::new();
    for ii in media.get_news() {
        news_list.push(ii)
    }
    news_list
}
```

When I compile the code I got the following error:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/lib.rs:38:45
   |
38 | fn news_filter<T: GetNews>(media: T) -> Vec<&News> {
   |                                             ^ help: consider giving it an explicit bounded or 'static lifetime: `&'static`
   |
   = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value with an elided lifetime, but the lifetime cannot be derived from the arguments
```

I tried to fix it according to the borrow checker like this:

```rust
fn news_filter<T: 'static + GetNews>(media: T) -> Vec<&'static News> {
    let mut news_list: Vec<&News> = Vec::new();
    for ii in media.get_news() {
        news_list.push(ii)
    }
    news_list
}
```

And I got this:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing function parameter `media`
  --> src/lib.rs:43:5
   |
40 |     for ii in media.get_news() {
   |               ----- `media` is borrowed here
...
43 |     news_list
   |     ^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I don't know how to solve this. I think the good way is to give the reference to the vector (news_list) but I don't know how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably want `&[News]` as a return value, don't you?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the answer, but I want to return a vector (or an array) of News references because I would like avoid to cloning the structure. Eventually I could return a &[&News] instead of a Vec<&News>.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.as_slice there is no copying involved, because it points to the underlying data of the `Vec` in memory. Therefore `&[News]` is totaly valid

Comment: In fact, I am just stupid. I just have to change T to &T (fn news_filter<T: GetNews>(media: &T) -> Vec<&News>).
Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `news_filter` really have to take by value? This way, the stuff within `T` can not be referenced after it has been consumed by the function.

I think you actually want `fn news_filter<T: GetNews>(media: &T) -> Vec<&News>`. (Playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b0e387ab264d98979ab3e68057401349)